# geoServer WFS call to iterate/loop over a string

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I would like to make a WFS call via POST that takes a value and checks if it is in a range on the features attributes. the attribute looks like this:

```
  <###:range>F 301-436,438-500,G 1</###:range> //these are on separate features.
  <###:range>C 201-400,D 1-100</###:range>
  <###:range>M 401-600</###:range>
  <###:range>B 1-144,146-310,312-400,F 1-400</###:range>
```

So if i had a letter and a number like 'F 310' I would like it to return the first and last feature.

I can't change the geoserver or data in any way.
I have looked into functions and can see that I could nest IF statements with INDEXOF and other string functions to manually check and take apart the string then use the BETWEEN function but this would be hard coded in regard to the length of the string to be broken apart and make a very verbose statement.

I will look more at the stored functions but Im having difficulty finding easy to digest information. I don't expect this to offer anything above what the standard call allows.

I am at the moment resorting to this processing on the client where loops make this job easy. It may well be that this is the 'correct' place to do the processing but before I close the door on this I wondered if anyone else had done a similar thing or have any cunning tricks.

EDIT:
I have found a function expression in the ECQL docs

```
<function> ::= <identifier> "(" ( <function arguments> ("," <function arguments> )* )? ")"
<function arguments> ::= <literal> | <attribute> | <expression>
```

This would seem to offer the ability to use recursion presuming the function is called (not some other function use) I can nest the 'IF $notFinished$ THEN thisFunction($subString$)' within it. I cannot however find any examples of how to use this within a POST request. -- this seems to be to access the standard functions not user created ones.